# How to execute a binary file in android shell

Tags: android, flutter, shell, dart, process

I want to run a binary file in android shell and i am using flutter and dart build in function

```
Process.run();
```

for creating a process in android shell.
But whenever I am trying to execute binary file it showing permission denied error, even it has executable permission, but it's working with `linker64`.
So my question is how execute this binary like other binary file (e.g: `./a.out`).
Thanks in advance.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWpvj.png)

Answer (score 0):

After doing some searching it looks like Google may be taking active steps to stop this from being possible. I've attached a relevant bug on the Google issue tracker below. A potential workaround for now would be targeting API 28 or below for your application, however this might make publishing your app on the play store harder. If your android version isn't too new, moving your binary to /data/local/bin before executing it might help. (https://curl-users.cool.haxx.narkive.com/RPS4Dfna/install-curl-in-android-using-binary)

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/128554619?pli=1

For interest's sake, the termux developers had the same issue a few years ago:
https://github.com/termux/termux-app/issues/1072